# What happens when tx is broadcasted whose input is not yet received by mempool or are unknown?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, nodes, peers

lets say, there are 2 `transactions`

```
tx1
address1 -> address2

tx2
address2 -> address3
```

our mempool doesnt have the `tx1` yet, but i try to create a `tx2` and broadcast it.

what will happen ?

will `tx2` get included in mempool ? and relayed to other nodes ?

or

`tx2` gets rejected. and wont be included in `mempool`  and wont be relayed to other `nodes` ?

what is the actual flow ?

what are such `tx` are called ?

What happens when tx is broadcasted whose input is not yet received by mempool ?or not in the old blocks i.e. missing/unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a transaction is called an *orphan transaction*.

When you announce a transaction to a peer who misses one or more of its inputs, the transaction will be placed in the *orphan pool* - where they are temporarily held in the hope that their dependencies arrive. A request will go out to fetch those dependencies from whoever sent us the transaction.

The transaction won't be relayed until it can be validated. Once all dependencies arrive, they will all be subject to normal validation and relay policies, and if acceptable, relayed in dependency order.

Comment: if i did the sendrawtransaction with such tx2, after getting it in our own mempool , who will  it send request for its dependencies ?